# Plot3D with a single contour highlighted. Different styles above and below

Tags: plotting

Here is a simple example that gives spurious results.

```
Plot3D[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1} , Mesh -> None, 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z}, 
If[z <= .5, Blue, Directive[White, Opacity[0.4]]]]]
```

[image]

1. Why is the blue-white "boundary" somewhere around a value of `-3.5`, not `0.5` as specified in the `ColorFunction`?
2. Why is the boundary so rough, the boundary should very obviously be a circle for this simple example?
3. How can fix these problems and draw a **clean smooth contour at the interface?**

**EDIT** How can I draw a single meshline at a desired height? For example:

```
Plot3D[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1} , MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> 1, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[Magenta, Thickness[0.02]], 
ColorFunction -> 
Function[{x, y, z}, 
If[z <= .6, Blue, Directive[White, Opacity[0.4]]]],PlotPoints->300]
```

does almost exactly what I want, except that I have no way to control the placement of this `1` Meshline. How can I control its height value?

[image]

This should be enough, as I can easily obscure the bumpy boundary with this clean meshline.

Comment: have you tried increasing the number of plotted points? For example adding the option `PlotPoints -> 100` or higher. With `400` I get a decently smooth separation

Comment: Yes, that improves it somewhat, but it never converges to a nice circle that we know it (is in this case). Ultimately, I need to extend the solution here to a `ListPlot3D` which comes from data I can't access analytically, and I want it to smooth over those tiny adjustments and just made a nice smooth thick line. (200 `PlotPoints` http://i.imgur.com/Ckvfpsy.png).

Comment: Yes, I agree that 400 plotpoints is roughly satisfactory in terms of smoothness, but my real problem involves a ListPlot3D of data that is taxing to generate and I will not be able to call for it on such a fine mesh. Surely there is a more sophisticated approach? Also, this doesn't address why the boundary appears where it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Plot3D[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Thick, Red],  
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{-3}}, 
 MeshShading -> {Blue, Opacity[.4, White]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, break the plotted surface into two parts and use `PlotStyle` to color the two parts and `BoundaryStyle` to color the border between the two pieces:

```
Plot3D[{ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] <= -3.], 
   ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], -Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] >= -3.]}, 
  {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> {1 -> None, 2 -> Directive[Thick, Red]}, 
  BoxRatios -> 1, Mesh -> None, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, Opacity[0.4, White]}] /. Line -> (Tube[#, .1] &)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update:** *Is there a good way to get the x,y meshlines back without disrupting this solution?*

```
Plot3D[-Sqrt[x^2 + y^2], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, BoxRatios -> 1, 
 MeshStyle -> {({Red, Tube @@ #} &), Directive[Thick, Yellow], Directive[Thick, Cyan]}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, # &, #2 &}, Mesh -> {{-3}, 10, 5}, 
 MeshShading -> {{{Blue, Opacity[0.4, White]}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Yes, very good. Thank you! http://i.imgur.com/E362CgA.png

Comment: Is there a good way to get the x,y meshlines back without disrupting this solution? http://i.imgur.com/jV9F2NH.png

Comment: I just can't figure out what rank it needs: http://i.imgur.com/dx7AxjZ.png

Comment: @Steve, thank you for the accept, Re adding the x and y mesh lines please see the update.

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution is perfect for me. However, for anyone who might read this page in the future, the `Tube @@ #` solution for the line seems to tie the size to the axes scale. For example, in my plot with x,y axes on the order of 10^(-12) this red "tube" fills the entire plot red. It works fine with just a `Directive[Red,Thickness[0.01]]` type MeshStyle though. Cheers.

Comment: @Steve, my pleasure. Glad it worked for you.